# Mybatis several jndi names

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi, mybatis

I have such kind of an issue: different web servers have different rules for jndi naming. So, for example, if in Tomcat I want to use jndi name for datasource it will look like:

```
<dataSource type="JNDI">
    <property name="data_source" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/myJndiName"/>
</dataSource>
```

But in WebSphere or Jboss, I will have to provide the jndi name without the "comp/env", something like just

```
<dataSource type="JNDI">
    <property name="data_source" value="java:jdbc/myJndiName"/>
</dataSource>
```

or the jndi name I provided in the configuration. If use the same name as in Tomcat, using the "comp/env" prefix, obviously, it won't work.

Is there a way, so I could make the app universal for different web services? I was thinking of writing my own DataSource wrap that would check for the jndi name availability and set it properly.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mybatis environments may be what you are looking for.

http://mybatis.github.com/mybatis-3/configuration.html#environments

In your case the config could look something like

```
<environments default="tomcat">
    <environment id="tomcat">
        <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>
        <dataSource type="JNDI">
            <property name="data_source" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/myJndiName"/>
        </dataSource>
    </environment>
    <environment id="websphere">
        <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>
        <dataSource type="JNDI">
            <property name="data_source" value="java:jdbc/myJndiName"/>
        </dataSource>
    </environment>
</environments>
```

You would need to create a sql session factory for each environment

```
InputStream in = Resources.getResourceAsStream("myconfig.xml");
SqlSessionFactory tomcatSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(in, "tomcat");
SqlSessionFactory websphereSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(in, "websphere");
```

Answer (score 1):

In OSGI environment (Aries JNDI), look up config should like below

```
<environment id="development">
   <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>
    <dataSource type="JNDI">
    <property name="data_source" value="osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/Ds)"/>
  </dataSource>
```